# C# Making a clickable list with names from a specific folder

Tags: c#, list, directory, readfile, clickable

Ive searched high and low for this but cant find it.

Im trying to make a list with names from a specific folder that holds a lot of text files. I want the list to be clickable so let's say if it show a name like "Name1" and i click it i want it to get me to a new form with a textbox showing the information from the textfile "Name1".

I hope ive explained my problem well enough so someone can help me and ill be very grateful for any help i can get!

Comment: What will you use: WPF, ASP, WinForms??

Comment: You have explained your __task__ well but not your __problem__. All the steps are really simple and fail to understand where you could get stuck?

Comment: Im using Winforms. Ive stil been unsuccesful so find a solution for this. Im not getting how to get the information to a list and access the file from the list....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a code write-my-code site, so I will only give you hints:

- Since you want to display text in a second form, add a second form to your project
- Since we want to work with files and folders, add the [`System.IO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace to both forms
- Since we want to tell the second form about the name of the file it will display, change its constructor to something like this:

---

```
    string fileName;
    public Form2(string fn)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fileName = fn;

    }
```

- Since you want to display a list, add a `ListBox` to the 1st Form
- Since you want to display a text, add a `TextBox` to the 2nd Form
- To get a list of filenames use `Directory.GetFiles()`
- To add the result to the `Items` of the `ListBox` use `ListBox.AddRange()` method
- To access the clicked one use `ListBox.SelectedItem` in the `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event
- Before using it check if there is a selection: `if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)..`
- Use `ToString()` on the `Item`
- Create a `new Form2(filename)` and `Show()` it
- There, use `File.ReadAllText` and assign the result to `textBox1.Text`

Please look up all the methods on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the right format and examples of their use!

Comment: I never expected anyone to give me the code i just wanted someone to point me in the right direction since im new and this answer is the best i could ever get! Thank u so much TaW :-D U made my day!